# How to decrease the distance between the sheet edge and the header?

Tags: vb.net

I need the header to come closer to the edge of the sheet. What property could I use for this?

There is already a line of code that creates the header.

```vb
Word_VB.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\CabecalhoWord.png")
```

But I can't move it up.

Anyone have a tip? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean reduce the Page Margin(s)?

Comment: No. If I make the page margin smaller, the body text goes up, but the header stays where it is. I need a command that actually goes up the header. Thanks Hursey!!